# exporting data mining structure data into a sql table

Tags: sql, ssas

I have a data mining structure in SSAS. I have drillthrough enabled so I can right click on a leaf and drill through to see the model and structure columns, I want to export that data into the sql table. Had a look around but havent managed to find anything that could help.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into exporting your data into a csv file, looks like [this is thread that might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047491/how-can-i-export-my-data-from-a-sass-cube-after-creating-a-query), and then load that csv file into the RDBMS of your choice.

There might be a way to load the data directly from SSAS, but I've always found exporting/importing csv files to be a very quick option for loading data.

Comment: is that also if I only want to export a specific leaf data  from the model.